# Stellar Node JS Payment Error

Tags: node.js, blockchain

I'm working on a simple API, we are using this SDK but when we try on live with this script.

```
var StellarSdk = require('stellar-sdk');
StellarSdk.Network.usePublicNetwork();

var keypair = StellarSdk.Keypair.fromSecret('OUR SECRET');
var server = new StellarSdk.Server('https://horizon.stellar.org');

var sourceKeypair = StellarSdk.Keypair.random();
console.log(sourceKeypair.publicKey());
console.log(sourceKeypair.secret());

var secret = sourceKeypair.secret();
var public = sourceKeypair.publicKey();



server.loadAccount(keypair.publicKey())
  .then(function(source) {
    var transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(source)
      .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.payment({
        destination: public,
        amount: "1",
        asset: StellarSdk.Asset.native()
      }))
      .build();

    transaction.sign(keypair);

    return server.submitTransaction(transaction);
})
.then(function() {
  return server.loadAccount(public)
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.error('Error!', error);
});
```

On the script we created a new account and we want  to activate it with 1 lumen, the secret of the Payment have at least 1000 lumens, but when we make the transactions, it give this error:

```
Error! { [BadResponseError: Transaction submission failed. Server responded: 400 Bad Request]
  name: 'BadResponseError',
  message: 'Transaction submission failed. Server responded: 400 Bad Request',
  data: 
   { type: 'https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/transaction_failed',
     title: 'Transaction Failed',
     status: 400,
     detail: 'The transaction failed when submitted to the stellar network. The `extras.result_codes` field on this response contains further details.  Descriptions of each code can be found at: https://www.stellar.org/developers/learn/concepts/list-of-operations.html',
     instance: 'horizon-001a/Fm1q5QnVH4-247091670',
     extras: 
      { envelope_xdr: 'AAAAACO0e3CpDcv7A+FzZkIdKI0Jqhln3kEwK3OsVJW6fOYMAAAAZADzojYAAAAaAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAA90HkP1W5wCsFRAGGKE1z1b+b7PnetRAQI6/XIo9R2PwAAAAAAAAAAACYloAAAAAAAAAAAbp85gwAAABAr1tWwYjH5fjEUL6gsgFCrJbQakDuSk6bE2AYE51NAZkH4N6f7JCkwAEH2A1XSG334sprokpxy7lWcVPW92XgBw==',
        result_codes: [Object],
        result_xdr: 'AAAAAAAAAGT/////AAAAAQAAAAAAAAAB////+wAAAAA=' } } }
```

Any advice?

Comment: did you fix above issue??

Comment: Hi @shankarkn yes i did, the problem seems the minimun balance for Stellar i don't know why but the minium is diferent over the docs.